# VSTS "Visual Studio Test" task can't find tests of .Net Core dlls

Tags: azure-devops, mstest, vstest

My VSTS - "**Visual Studio Test**" task can't find any tests of the .NET Core assembly. But in VS 2017 and in the console, it works well.

**VSTS Task's logs:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**My run settings file:**

[image]

Comment: Please don't post code as image, use text.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Refer to these additional settings of Visual Studio Test task:

1. Path to vstest.console.exe: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform`
2. Other console options: `/framework:".NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0"`

Comment: How do I do this for a mixed solution containing net461 and netcoreapp2.1 apps?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue where the cause was I had copied a semi-colon separated search pattern in the "Test files" field from my `v1` Visual Studio Test task definition to my `v2` definition

Apparently v2 does not support semi-colon separation so i changed to new-line separation and it worked.

I.e. changed `build/Tests/*Test.dll;-:**\obj\**` 
to

`build/Tests/*Test.dll
-:**\obj\**`

Answer (score 0):

Remove `<TargetFrameworkVersion>Framework45</TargetFrameVersion>` from runsettings.

As mentioned in warning message(Following DLL(s) do not match framework/platform), vstest.console ignoring .NET Core test-assemblies because the TargetFrameworkVersion value(Framework45) in runsettings.

You can remove TargetFrameworkVersion from runsettings if you are using VS >= 15.5. From 15.5 vstest.console has capability to detect framework and platform by reading metadata from test-assembly.

Comment: Thanks to your reply, but I tried to remove it and it doesn't work. The same messages...

Answer (score 0):

Commonly this is caused by a lack of a test adapter for the framework you're using.  For example for nunit you need to use `nunitTestAdapter`.